# How to move DNN module to different DNN install

Tags: vb.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have a DNN version 5 site that has modules that I want to move to another newer DNN 7 site.  In the file system for the DNN 5 install I have that module as a collection of .ascx and .vb files.  I also have the .dnn file.

I've been searching around how to do this and it seems that I need to package these all those .ascx and .vb files together  to install them in my DNN 7 site.  Is there no way to simply install them directly from the .dnn manifest file that I have?

Packaging the files up seems pretty involved, such as getting the Visual Studio project templates and using those, etc.  But I don't want to create modules right now, I just want to move an existing one from one DNN site to another.  Do I really need to get into the whole module development ecosystem just to do that task?

Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

1. Do it in visual studio using my templates (longer and more involved, but better if you want to make changes down the road)
2. Copy all the Files in the desktopmodules/MODULENAME folder from one install to the other. Copy the DLL in the BIN folder. Go to the Host/Extensions page on the install you want, click the Create New Module button, in the FROM option, choose from MANIFEST and find the .DNN file.
3. You can go to the Host/Extensions page of the install with the existing module, click the Edit pencil next to the module you want to move. Choose the "create package" option, you'll be walked through the process for creating a ZIP file for the module.

I prefer option #1, the 2 and 3 in order. #1 because it is the better way to do things long term.